# Display Loading spinner waitint for request to complete while using provider package

Tags: flutter, future, provider

I am using a provider package. I want to display a loading spinner while waiting for a request to complete. The pattern below is too verbose. Please help me make it less verbose. Here is my code

```dart
class APIService with ChangeNotifier {
  // Check for working API backend
  bool isWorking = false;
  bool isLoading = false;

  set _isLoading(bool value) {
    isLoading = value;        <-- 
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> selectAPI(String input) async {
    _isLoading = true;        <-- 1
    final uri = Uri.tryParse('https://$input$url')!;
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final body = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      bool isTrue = body['info']['title'] == 'SamFetch';
      _isLoading = false;     <-- 2
      notifyListeners();
      return isWorking = isTrue;
    }
    _isLoading = false;       <-- 3
    throw response;
  }
}
```

Here is my UI code

```dart
    IconButton(
       icon: apiService.isLoading
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : Icon(Icons.done),
              onPressed: () async {
              await addAPI(apiService, cache);      
       }),

}
```

Below is addAPI() method

```dart
  Future<void> addAPI(APIService apiService, Cache cache) async {
    if (api != null) {
      try {
        await apiService.selectAPI(api!);
        if (apiService.isWorking) {
          await cache.saveAppName(api!);
        }
      } on SocketException catch (e) {
        print(e);
      } catch (e) {
        await cache.clearCache();
      }
    }
  }
```

Is `setState` the final solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Future Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and set your Future Function in `future` attribute. You can control the visible widget based on the status of your function. So you dont have to use `isloading` variable.

Comment: I want to request while user press button